# Make sure RMI only operates on one Server instance

Tags: java, rmi

I am currently trying to grab the basics of RMI by implementing a Server/Client Structure where both the Client can invoke remote Operations on the Server, and the Server can invoke Client functions:

```
public class Client extends GenericRMI implements ClientInterface {
    public ServerInterface server;

    public Client() {
    try {
        String IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

        server = (ServerInterface) Naming.lookup("//192.168.2.124/WServer");

        int uniqueID = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);

        super.setUpRMI("WClient" + IP + "_" + uniqueID);

        server.registerNewClient(IP, uniqueID);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

public void setUserID(int id) {
    System.out.println("got my ID from the server: " + id);
}
}

public class Server extends GenericRMI implements ServerInterface {
private List<ClientInterface> clients;

public Server() {
    clients = new ArrayList<ClientInterface>();
    super.setUpRMI("WServer");
}

public void registerNewClient(String IP, int uID) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        ClientInterface c = (ClientInterface) Naming.lookup("//" + IP + "/WClient" + IP + "_"
                + uID);
        int newID = clients.size();
        clients.add(c);
        c.setUserID(newID);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and, in the main function:

```
new Server();
Thread.sleep(1000);
new Client();

Thread.sleep(1000);
new Client();

Thread.sleep(1000);
new Client();
```

interfaces are defined by

```
public interface ServerInterface extends Remote...
```

RMI setup

```
public class GenericRMI implements Remote, Serializable {
protected Registry registry;

public void setUpRMI(String bindName) {
    if (registry == null) {
        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
        } catch (ExportException e) {
            // client and server on one PC
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        Naming.rebind(bindName, this);
    } catch (RemoteException | MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Started " + bindName);
}
}
```

however, output is like

```
Started WServer
Started WClient192.168.2.124_501
got my ID from the server: 0
Started WClient192.168.2.124_655
got my ID from the server: 0
Started WClient192.168.2.124_771
got my ID from the server: 0
```

even if i debug it, the server has a different ID for each client. I guess I am doing a terrible mistake somewhere, since I used to think that the server would only have ONE instance running. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT**
the Problem is; if i debug the registerNewClient() function, the respective Server object changes for each Client:
    Server@7728992
    Server@5fbb71ac
    ...
Even if i make the clients' list synchronized, it doesn't help. However, making the clients field transient server-side leads to a null pointer exception on it, indicating that it indeed is a new instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have only one instance running. You only called `new Server()` once, and in any case there's no way three instances can be bound to the same name in the Registry. More likely you have a concurrency problem on the unsynchronized 'clients' collection.

Comment: the Problem is; if i debug the registerNewClient() function, the respective Server object changes for each Client:
Server@7728992
Server@5fbb71ac
...
Even if i make the clients' list synchronized, it doesn't help. However, making the clients field transient server-side leads to a null pointer exception on it, indicating that it indeed is a new instance.

Comment: You need to make GenericRMI extend UnicastRemoteObject. At the movement it isn't a remote object at all.